# Getting multiple UUIDs in Json from URL

Tags: java, json

I am working on a cosmetics base for a Minecraft client I'm making. I am using a json file on GitHub [(here)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shovelmods/shovelmods.github.io/main/cosmetics.json) with UUIDs of players which I am trying to give cosmetics to, I am trying to put UUIDs into a List which gives those players the item (the names don't do anything, I just have them so I know which id is who). So far I have been able to give the right cosmetic to UUIDs but only hardcoded into the client, I don't want to have to export my workspace every time I need to add someone to the list so I want to try get it to talk to a file online. Here is my current code:

```
private static List<UUID> players = new ArrayList<UUID>();

public static boolean hasCape(AbstractClientPlayer player) {
    
    players.add(UUID.fromString("288f696b-44d2-4915-a8cc-aa3fd5ea889c")); //jamig
    players.add(UUID.fromString("ecad61c5-6a42-4018-b1c7-6c5c19ec1cd1")); //cxplxsok
    players.add(UUID.fromString("093f3473-587b-4a2a-b50f-f4a136e9033b")); //DarylHotstuff69
    players.add(UUID.fromString("a22ab0ef-18b2-4cc6-ac17-2d9ae40a42ee")); //chfff
    
    for(UUID uuid : players) {
        if(player.getUniqueID().equals(uuid)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
    
}
```

Comment: Either way, you are adding the elements to the players list every time you call hasCape. The more you call it, the longer it will take and the more memory it will consume. Add the items beforehand, e.g. in the static initializer.

Comment: Also, you can simplify the method to `return players.contains(player.getUniqueID());`.

Comment: Yeah I just thought about adding the items in initialiser just after posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be best off using a library to parse json for you. In your case, `com.google.code.gson.gson` is included in Minecraft already. Using a json string as input (read from the file), you can parse it using something like:

```java
String json = ...; // Your json.
JsonArray jsonArr = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject jsonObj = jsonArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    String name = jsonObj.get("name").getAsString();
    String uuid = jsonObj.get("uuid").getAsString();
    // Do something with the name and uuid.
}
```

Note that you might have to put the data in your file between `[]`'s to indicate that it is an array.

Comment: Worth noting the the Json may be retrieved using http from the github link in the question.

Comment: This worked great! I modified it to take the json from Github as well, thanks!